# Second Player Movement Input Lagging

Tags: c#, game-physics, lag

**Greetings!**

I'm pretty new to C# and I've been following a playlist of tutorials from YouTube to create the application in question. However, now that I'm one video short from finishing the series, I decided to try and give the game a little bit of my own twist. The game is very basic, there's a *playerUnit* (the main player), an *enemyUnit* (the enemy) and the *allyUnit* (the second player). I created the *allyUnit* simply as practice at the beginning of the tutorial series, not even thinking about turning it into a second player ever. However, with the knowledge acquired from the other episodes, I decided to make it into a second player. In its own script, I simply used the same code for movement I used for the *playerUnit*, only changing the movement keys. However, while the *playerUnit* responds right as you press the key and instantly moves, the second player lags. It will take a while before it starts moving and sometimes moves in different intervals.

In the **Game.cs** script, in the **lines 43 and 44**, inside **public void Run()**, I noticed that if I switch *playerUnit.Update* with *allyUnit.Update*, *allyUnit* will no longer lag but *playerUnit* will. So whichever appears first in the code will not lag, the other will. This makes me think that it could be some conflict with the Update? Since it's updating key inputs at the same time, in the same cycle or something? Given I'm still learning, I might be saying the biggest blasphemy ever, but that's also why I'm creating this thread.

Here are the relevant scripts:

**Game.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DodgeGame
{
    public class Game
    {
        public Game () //This function runs when the player starts a New Game, thus creating the characters
        {
            //Creates a player unit and sets its position/graphic
            playerUnit = new PlayerUnit(30, 10, "@");

            //Creates an enemy unit and sets its position/graphic
            enemyUnit = new EnemyUnit(Console.WindowWidth - 1, 10, "X");

            //Creates an ally unit and sets its position/graphic
            allyUnit = new AllyUnit(12, 5, "O");

            stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        }

        private Stopwatch stopwatch;

        private Unit playerUnit;
        private Unit enemyUnit;
        private Unit allyUnit;

        public void Run() //This function is called once the New Game has begun, thus drawing the characters
        {
            stopwatch.Start ();
            int timeAtPreviousFrame = (int)stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds; //timeAtPreviousFrame -- milliseconds the stopwatch reported last frame


            while (true) 
            {
                //Time since last frame
                int deltaTimeMS = (int)(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds - timeAtPreviousFrame); //1000 / desiredFPS;
                timeAtPreviousFrame = (int)stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                //Update units
                playerUnit.Update (deltaTimeMS);
                allyUnit.Update (deltaTimeMS);
                enemyUnit.Update (deltaTimeMS);

                //Detect collide (True = Game Over)
                if (playerUnit.IsCollidingWith (enemyUnit) || allyUnit.IsCollidingWith(enemyUnit))
                {
                    GameOver ();    
                }

                //Draws all units
                playerUnit.Draw ();
                allyUnit.Draw ();
                enemyUnit.Draw ();

                //Tiny sleep to avoid running at too high FPS
                Thread.Sleep (5);   
            }
        }

        void GameOver()
        {
            Console.Clear ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Game Over!");
            Console.WriteLine ("\n\nWould you like to try again? (Y/N)");

            while(true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey (true);

                switch(cki.Key)
                {
                case ConsoleKey.Y:
                    Console.Clear ();
                    Game game = new Game ();
                    game.Run ();
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.N:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**AllyUnit.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DodgeGame
{
    public class AllyUnit : Unit
    {
        public AllyUnit (int x, int y, string unitGraphic) : base(x, y, unitGraphic)    {       }

        override public void Update(int deltaTimeMS)
        {
            //Ally Actions

            //Has the second player pressed a key?
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)       // Yes
            { 
                //This will make the second player move
                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey (true);

                switch (cki.Key) 
                {
                    //Move Up
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:    case ConsoleKey.NumPad8:
                        if (Y > 0)
                            Y = Y - 1;

                        break;

                    //Move Down
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:  case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                        if (Y < Console.WindowHeight - 1)
                            Y = Y + 1;

                        break;

                    //Move Left
                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:  case ConsoleKey.NumPad4:
                        if (X > 0)
                            X = X - 1;

                        break;

                    //Move Right
                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow: case ConsoleKey.NumPad6:
                        if (X < Console.WindowWidth - 1)
                            X = X + 1;

                        break;
                }

                //With Ally Actions calculated, we want to call Unit's Update in case it has important work to do
                base.Update (deltaTimeMS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PlayerUnit.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DodgeGame
{
    public class PlayerUnit : Unit
    {
        public PlayerUnit (int x, int y, string unitGraphic) : base(x, y, unitGraphic)
        {

        }

        override public void Update(int deltaTimeMS)
        {
            //====================================================================\\
            //                           PLAYER ACTIONS                           \\
            //====================================================================\\

            //Has the user pressed a key?
            if (Console.KeyAvailable == true) // Yes
            {
                //This will make the player move
                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey (true);

                switch(cki.Key)
                {
                    //Move Up
                    case ConsoleKey.W: case ConsoleKey.NumPad8:
                        if(Y > 0)
                            Y = Y - 1;

                        break;

                    //Move Down
                    case ConsoleKey.S: case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                        if(Y < Console.WindowHeight - 1)
                            Y = Y + 1;

                        break;

                    //Move Left
                    case ConsoleKey.A: case ConsoleKey.NumPad4:
                        if(X > 0)   
                            X = X - 1;

                        break;

                    //Move Right
                    case ConsoleKey.D: case ConsoleKey.NumPad6:
                        if(X < Console.WindowWidth - 1)
                            X = X + 1;

                        break;
                }
            }

            //With keyboard input received, we want to call Unit's Update in case it has important work to do
            base.Update (deltaTimeMS);
        }
    }
}
```

**Unit.cs**

```
using System;

namespace DodgeGame
{
    abstract public class Unit
    {
        public Unit(int x, int y, string unitGraphic)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
            this.UnitGraphic = unitGraphic;
        }

        //Unit's Position
        public int X //The way the rest of the program interacts with X
        {
            get
            {
                return _x;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value < 0 || value >= Console.WindowWidth)
                {
                    throw new Exception ("Invalid X Coordinate."); 
                }

                Clean ();
                _x = value;
            }
        }
        private int _x; //Where the value of X is actually stored

        //Unit's Position
        public int Y //The way the rest of the program interacts with X
        {
            get
            {
                return _y;
            }
            set
            {
                if(value < 0 || value >= Console.WindowHeight)
                {
                    throw new Exception ("Invalid Y Coordinate."); 
                }

                Clean ();
                _y = value;
            }
        }
        private int _y; //Where the value of X is actually stored

        //====================================================================\\

        //Unit's Graphics
        public string UnitGraphic {get; set;}

        //Update Unit's Position
        virtual public void Update(int deltaTimeMS)
        {

        }

        //This draws the units on the screen
            public void Draw()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition (X, Y);
            Console.Write (UnitGraphic);
        }

        public void Clean()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition (X, Y);
            Console.Write(' ');
        }

        public bool IsCollidingWith(Unit other)
        {
            if (this.X == other.X && this.Y == other.Y)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }    
    }
}
```

I tried creating a different separate *Update()* function exclusively for *allyUnit* but it didn't work. I also tried several other minor things but none of them did the job. What can I do to fix this?

Thank you in advance,

Nervly

Comment: Welcome game-creating good sir.  Is it possible for you to post the relevant code in your question rather than link it? [mcve].    Good luck!

Comment: Done! Sorry for not doing it right away, it was for the sake of keeping the post short but I can see how it becomes more convenient this way. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score -1):

My suspicion is the fact that both your PlayerUnit and AllyUnit Update() methods call ReadKey(). When whichever Update() method is called first will grab the key pressed, leaving no key press event left for the second method call.

It is poor form to include any sort of I/O directly into your logic classes anyway so what I would do is make a separate Update function in Game.cs that reads the key, then passes the key read to the PlayerUnit.Update() and AllyUnit.Update() calls.

Edit:
So something like this in Game.cs:

```
Update(mSecs) {
  ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey();
  playerUnit.Update(cki, mSecs);
  allyUnit.Update(cki, mSecs);
  enemyUnit.Update(mSecs);
}
```

And then change the methods in the *Unit classes accordingly.
You'll have to also change the Run() method to replace the Update calls with a call to this method instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Would you be able to give me so hints on how to achieve this, please? I've been trying several things to get to where you suggested me but so far I haven't been able to get it right.

Comment: Edited the answer to give a hint about what to do.  You might have to change the enemyUnit.Update to take a ConsoleKeyInfo type too, even though it wouldn't use it, to make your existing inheritance structure work out.

Comment: I finally managed to fix it! Thank you so much for your help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yup! I created separate Update methods for the Player and Ally and then sent the cki from Game.cs to both their Updates. Worked like a charm!

EDIT: Actually, is it possible to keep the movement of the players going even when another key is pressed? Let's say I'm player one and I'm holding down D to go to the right (instead of repeatedly pressing it). As it stands, if any other key is pressed, the movement is interrupted. So both players have to repeatedly press their movement keys if they want to keep moving which, after some testing, becomes extremely annoying. How can I fix this?

Comment: You may have to find another API call (if the Console* functions don't already provide it) of getting the key press and key release events.  That way you simply start moving on press, stop moving on release.  Check the methods on consolekeyinfo object.  See if you can find anything

Comment: @Nervly know it's been awhile, but if my answer helped you, mind accepting it?